# TCPDump To Capture A Tracepath6 Datagram

Tags: networking, ipv6, tcpdump, pcap

I'm trying to use TCPDump to capture an IPv6 datagram using:

```
tcpdump -c 1 -i eth1 -vvvs0 ip6 and dst host H2.net2 & tracepath6 H2.net2
```

I'm running this script on H1.net1; R12.net1 is the net1 interface for a router connecting net1 and net2; Both H1 and H2 are IPv6 enabled, as is R12.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
tcpdump: expression rejects all packets
```

The way I'm seeing it: I'm telling it to listen for and capture 1 ipv6 datagram destined for H2, then I'm sending an ipv6 datagram to H2 for it to capture.

What am I missing?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think that the hostname resolution returns an IPv4 address, which is contradictory with `ip6`. I don't know how to solve this (other than resolving the IPv6 address with some other tool and passing it to `tcpdump`).

Comment: What is `H2.net2`?